# How to get the document which likes within the extent in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to get all the document which  lines within or intersects the extent of polygon drawn. I have wrote the query but not working. My query is :

> db.ab_postal.find({ 'geometry': {$geoIntersects : { $geometry : { type: 'polygon' , coordinates :  [-233510.5939202742, 7790549.737634793, -232936.0268500297, 7790896.716449941] }  }}})

My document structure is:

[image: Document Structure]

Any suggestion will be of great help.Thanks

Comment: You need to be more precise regarding "within or intersects", see [Spatial predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM#Spatial_predicates). Maybe you have to use 3rd party library, e.g. [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/)

Comment: I am looking for intersects